# how to setup property in string.xml?

Tags: android

i want to create an application in android ,for two country like U.S. or Japan.

my problem is that ,In my login or Registration forms labels are designed for once and use for both senario(countries).

This make sence by String.xml file . but how can ?

If any body knows then please give me idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is a bit confusingly written. As i understand it, you want to use the same layout for the two different countries but different String.xml files. Is that the case?

Comment: Next time, you should be sure that you dont use SMS like language. Because everybody here may not understand the SMS like short word language.

Comment: Exactly but i am  using same String.xml files.

Comment: thanks,my english is not well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create sub folders for different locale in the `res` folder.

Example:

```
res/values
res/values-in
res/values-fr
```

Copy strings.xml into those folders. One file per folder.

After that, change the languages for each strings.xml in respective to the folder. e.g., values-in for Indonesia, values-fr for France, etc.

Read this guide to further more explanation:
[Android Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)